# Как реализовать список любимых айтемов исходя из существующего списка?

Tags: android, recyclerview

ребят есть `TabLayout` и `ViewPager`, а он отображает два фрагмента в одном фрагменте есть некий список айтемов с чекбоксами, а второй фрагмент показывает все чекнутые айтемы из первого списка. айтемы отображены с помощью `recyclerview`. сразу покажу отрывок, из адаптера:

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CardViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Card card = cardList.get(position);

    holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(holder.imageView.getResources().getDrawable(card.getImage()));
    holder.textViewHeading.setText(card.getHeading());
    holder.textViewDescription.setText(card.getDescription());
    holder.checkBox.setChecked(card.isEnabled());
    holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                card.setEnabled(b);
        }
    });
}
```

данные во втором фрагменте (список любимых айтемов) обновляю, когда перелистываю страницу....:

```
  viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (position == 0){
                DataUtil.refreshChosenList();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
}
```

но ничего не происходит. Не знаю правильно повесил листенер на чекбокс?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
сделайте ваши фрагменты подклассами вашего активити.
в onPageChangedListener if(pos==1) второй адаптер notifyDataSetChanged();
в втором фрагменте в адаптере добавте список который хранит integer позицию в втором адаптере.
в втором фрагменте в адаптере добавте методы addItem(int pos)добавляет в список pos и в список в котором хранятся Card добавить Card из списка первого адаптера get(pos) через метод add(cardlist.size(),card) и в конце notifyItemInserted(poslist.get(pos)) ,
removeItem(int pos){
int posi=poslist.get(pos);
cardlist.remove(posi);
notifyItemRemoved(posi);
}
и в onBindViewHolder checkedListener if(b)adapter2.addItem(position); else adapter2.removeItem(position);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (position == 0)
```

Больше похоже что Вы обновляете список когда перелистываете на первый фрагмент, а не на второй.